No sound in the right ear when these headphones connected to a tablet via Bluetooth
I got these Srhythm NC25 Bluetooth headphones.
The problem is when connected via Bluetooth to my tablet, there is no sound in right ear.
When I connect them to my PC via Bluetooth, everything is fine.
When I connect them through a wire to PC or a tablet, everything is fine.
No sound in the right ear is only when I connect them via Bluetooth to a tablet, Samsung Galaxy Tab A.
What could be a problem?

Other than trying to re-pair the headphones to the tablet, I would edit the post to include which audio sources you are testing against (Youtube, Spotify, other) on the Android device. (And the standard, turn-off then turn-on both devices)
